# preg_match PHP various cases

Tags: php, regex

I want to make preg match stop when it reaches "Ho" or "<". How can i do that?

I tried using [Ho<] but it doesn't work beacause it does "H" or "o" or "<".

Thanks.

Example:

```
if(preg_match('/class="PuntoVentaDireccion">(.*?)[Ho<].*?Ventas\((.*?)\)</is', $info_tienda, $data)){
        echo $data[1];
        echo $data[2];
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "make preg match _stop_".

Comment: Do you have an example of the string before and after?

Comment: Your regex `[Ho<]` doesn't work because a character class allows any of the characters inside it, e.g. `H`, `o`, **or** `<`. That is how character classes are designed. http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can understand you want to use a [non capturing group `(?:...)`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) and [alternation `a|b`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
if (preg_match('/class="PuntoVentaDireccion">(.*?)(?:Ho|<).*?Ventas\((.*?)\)</is', $info_tienda, $data)) {
    echo $data[1];
    echo $data[2];
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! I was missing the non capturing group! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Marchu I'm happy that I could help. I linked a few interesting reads for deeper insight in how these works.